# Dealing with Alias URLs in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am rewriting our company website in cakephp, and need to find a way to do the following:

1. A user enters our site by using one
   of the promotional alias URLS that
   has been pregenerated for a specific
   media advert ( magazine, web
   promotion etc )
2. The URL is checked against a
   database of alias URLs, and if an
   alias exists, then a specific
   tracking code is written into the
   session.

I have considered several options, none of which seem suitable for this purpose. They are:

1. Putting the lookup script in the
   beforeFilter() in appcontroller, so
   that its included in every
   controller. (Writes a session value
   so it only perfoms once.)

   - This option only works for existing contollers, and gives the
     Cake 'missing controller' error if a
     URL doesn't exist.
2. Specific routes for each alias in
   Routes.php - Works but there are
   potentially hundreds of alias urls
   added/removed regularly via admin
   interface.
3. Route all site URLs to their own
   actions, and having an 'everything
   else' rule, for the alias URLs that
   maps to my lookup script. - Messy
   and I lose the built in Cake
   routing.
4. Custom 404. -  I don't want to
   return 404's for these urls, as I
   feel its bad practice unless they
   really don't map to anything.

I really could do with a place in the application flow where I can put this lookup/tracking script, and I'm fairly new to cake so I'm stumped.

EDIT: Also, I know that a subfolder called say 'promo' would easily do this, but I have a lot of legacy URLS from our old site, that need handling too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very interesting question.  I think I would use item #3.  It's not really *that* messy -- after all, this typically is handled by the pages controller in my stuff.  That's how I'd handle it - hardcode your routes to your controllers in routes.php, then have a matchall route that will work for your promo codes.  This allows you to keep legacy URLs, as well as use a lot of the standard cake stuff (you probably will just have to explicitly state each of your controllers routes, not such a chore...)  Additionally, it will let you do some cool stuff with 404 errors -- you can put some logic in there to try and figure out where they were trying to go, so you can superpower your 404's.

Comment: You don't have to state each controllers routes, you just have to state each controller - like '/my_controller/:action/'

Comment: gnud, can you post an example route please? I'm unsure of that syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Try Router::connect('/mycontroller/:action/*', array('controller' =>'mycontroller'));
Keep in mind that now you have to specify an action for the route to kick in, just going to /mycontroller/ won't work (IIRC)

Comment: great thanks! would i have to do the same for the pages controller though?

Answer (score 5):

Note: I'm making an assumption that your promo URLs are in the form of "domain.com/advert-259" or something like that (i.e. no "domain.com/**adverts**/advert-259'). That would be just too simple :)

Hopefully, you can use the routing with some regex. Add this to your /config/routes.php and let me know if a different regex will help :)

```
$controllers = Configure::listObjects('controller');

foreach ($controllers as &$value)
{
    $value = Inflector::underscore($value);
}

Router::connect('/:promo', array('controller' => 'promos', 'action' => 'process'), array('promo' => '(?!('.implode('|', $controllers).')\W+)[a-zA-Z\-_]+/?$'));
```

Now you can handle all your promo codes in `PromosController::process()`.

Basically, it checks for a promo code in url, *excluding* those in the $controllers array (i.e. your regular routes won't be messed up).

Later on you might want to consider caching the value of `Configure::listObjects()` depending on the speed of your app and your requirements.

Comment: thanks for this Dr Lecter. I have some reading to do on routes I think. In the meantime try not to kill anyone.